# How to trigger Views exposed filter AJAX autosubmit?

Tags: views

Drupal 7: I have a set of exposed filters on a View which are set to autosubmit and the View is set to use AJAX to update.

I want to trigger the autosubmit from Javascript code. Suggestions appreciated.